# Solr - Tika - Parsing Content to Enable Highlighting

Tags: solr, highlighting, apache-tika

My understanding is that indexing a PDF, Word, Excel, etc. document through Solr will allow searching but not highlighting. I have this code to perform the indexing:

```
        String urlString = "http://localhost:8983/solr"; 
        SolrServer solr = new HttpSolrServer(urlString);
        ContentStreamUpdateRequest up = new ContentStreamUpdateRequest("/update/extract");

        for (MultipartFile file : files) {
            if (file.getOriginalFilename().equals("")) {
                continue;
            }
            File destFile = new File(destPath, file.getOriginalFilename());
            file.transferTo(destFile);
            up.addFile(destFile);

            up.setParam("literal.id", destFile.getAbsolutePath());
            up.setAction(AbstractUpdateRequest.ACTION.COMMIT, true, true);

            try {
                solr.request(up);

            } catch (SolrServerException sse) {
                sse.printStackTrace();
            }

        }

    }
    } catch (IOException ioe) {
      ioe.printStackTrace();   
    }
```

I have read that in order to enable highlighting I will need to "store/parse the content?" How can this be done? Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to modify the [Schema](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SchemaXml) file for your Solr instance and set `stored="true"`for the `content` field. I am assuming that you are using the default field settings for the [ExtractingRequestHandler](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/ExtractingRequestHandler) want to return highlight results against that field.

Please reference the [Field Options By Use Case](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/FieldOptionsByUseCase) for a matrix and notes on what field options must be enabled for Highlighting and other features to work correctly.

Comment: Thanks Paige. I did not find a content field in the schema. I could create one, but it seems that the text field is already indexing the data. Is there any issue with changing its stored from false to true? Also, I have not changed any settings on the ExtractingRequestHandler.

Comment: No, there is not any issue with changing the stored value on the text field, since I am assuming this on the one that you want to highlight against.

Comment: That's correct. It appears that the default setting for ExtractingRequestHandler is to store its content into the text field (see below). So, I'll just keep that default and change the stored value on the text field. ( <requestHandler name="/update/extract" 
                  startup="lazy"  
                  class="solr.extraction.ExtractingRequestHandler" >
    <lst name="defaults">
      <!-- All the main content goes into "text"... if you need to return
           the extracted text or do highlighting, use a stored field. -->
      <str name="fmap.content">text</str>)